# how to add multiple edges using javascript function in orientDB

Tags: javascript, orientdb, graph-databases

I have added multiple nodes using the javascript function and wish to add edges to connect them when I try to write a for loop, it throws the following exception:

> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Impossible to serialize invalid link :#57:-2 in embedded session

If I write the same query without the for loop, it gets executed.

```
var g = orient.getGraph();
for (var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++ ){
var title ="post_0";
var company_name = "Company_0";
var c = "create edge HasInterest from (select from post where Title = '" + 
title + "') to (select from Interest where      Name = 'Recruitment')"; 
    g.command("sql",c,[]);
}
```

Comment: Is the for loop supposed to iterate through post_0, post_1, etc..?

Comment: yes, I have uploaded the hardcoded version, it will be "post_" + i

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a commit() statement since you're using a loop as such:

```
var g = orient.getGraph();
for (var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++ )
{
    var title = "post_" + i;
    var company_name = "Company_" + i;
    var c = "create edge HasInterest from (select from post where Title = '" +
             title + "') to (select from Interest where Name = 'Recruitment')";
    g.command("sql",c,[]);
    g.commit();
}
```